# What are the needed locales for dialog scripts to display correctly?

Tags: locale, dialog

I'm writing some custom installers that will work on Ubuntu and I'm using the `dialog` utility to help simplify the process of getting user input.

Sometimes, I notice that the extended ASCII that dialog outputs (such as line frames around text boxes) is not displayed correctly. (you get the circle with a question mark in it). This seems to happen when a system has been provisioned using the PXE/Netboot installer.

I'm wondering, given that the only language I need to support is English, what locale I should check for and suggest installing prior to launching dialog?

I've noticed this across multiple releases, my question isn't specific to a certain release.

Answer (score 1):

- Encoding is the only part of locale that should matter in this case, make sure that it's UTF-8.
- Check that the font you use in a terminal contains the line-drawing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
LC_ALL=C ./yourscript.sh
```

or

```
LC_ALL=en_EN.UTF-8 ./yourscript.sh
```

to get reliable results. At least the first one shouldn't need further installations.